# Counterexample for a complex analysis proof

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I'm having troubles coming up with a counterexample for the following: If $|f(z)|$ is continuous at $z_0$, then the function $f(z)$ is continuous at $z_0$ for complex numbers.

I know I need a $f(z)$ that is discontinuous at that $z_0$, where $|f(z)|$ is not.

Does anyone know of one that would work?

Comment: $$f(z) = \begin{cases} \frac{\overline{z}}{z} &, z \neq 0\\i &, z = 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: sorry can you explain why?

Comment: Because $f$ attains _every_ complex number of absolute modulus $1$ as a value in _every_ neighbourhood of $0$. However, $\lvert f(z)\rvert \equiv 1$ is continuous.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(z) = \begin{cases} 1, & z=z_0 & \\ -1, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.
Then $|f(z)| = 1$, is continuous, and $f$ is  discontinuous at $z=z_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $r(z)$ be a real-valued everywhere discontinuous function, and put $f(z) = e^{ir(z)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f(z) = z/|z|$ for $z\not= 0$ and $f(0) = 1.$